# Perl script to remove new line character and move next line data to previous line

Tags: perl

I have input like below

```
"ID"|"Desc"
"100"|"
The data present in Desc column has new line characters.
So the data came to second line.
Some records of data went to third line. But I need all data to be present in first line."
"101"|"This record desc is correct data which has present in single line. So I need data to present in single line."
```

I need output like below,

```
"ID"|"Desc"
"100"|"The data present in Desc column has new line characters.So the data came to second line.Some records of data went to third line. But I need all data to be present in first line."
"101"|"This record desc is correct data which has present in single line. So I need data to present in single line."
```

Can someone please help the Perl script where we can achieve above requirement.

Comment: Would you like a solution in powershell?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV_XS) to process the file as it can parse it correctly.

```
perl -MText::CSV_XS=csv -wE 'csv( in           => shift,
                                  always_quote => 1,
                                  sep_char     => "|",
                                  eol          => "\n",
                                  on_in        => sub { $_[1][1] =~ s/\n//g } );
' -- file.csv > newfile.csv
```

I'm testing this in a Linux shell, you might need a different `eol` if you're in MSWin. Also, I don't know what rules Powershell uses for quoting, co you might need to use a different type of quotes.

Comment: we are using txt file as input and we may require txt file as output and we need to run this script in windows server.

Comment: @Satish: I don't understand how this information is relevant.